# How to show arrays in the debugger in C#

Tags: c#, debugging, extension-methods

It's a common problem: the debugger shows your little array as `System.String[]` or similar but you want to see the values without having to click and open. How to do that?

I have an answer. Perhaps you have a better one.

Comment: Use `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SebastianSchulz: How would that work? Is it a proposed answer?

Comment: It was just an idea. The problem is, you cannot add this attribute to System.String[] but if you have a class containing the array you want to debug, you can add this attribute to the class and define a way how you want to display it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a templated extension method that looks like this.

```
  public static class UtilExtensions {
    // string join that works on any enumerable
    public static string Join<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, string delim) {
      return String.Join(delim, values.Select(v => v == null ? "null" : v.ToString()));
    }
```

Because this is templated you can use it on any type of array (or List or whatever). Don't forget to include a `use` for the namespace!

Then add a ToString() method to your class that looks like this:

```
  public struct CommonRow {
    public object[] Values;
    public override string ToString() {
      return Values.Join(",");
    }
  }
```

And magically, everywhere there is a value of type CommonRow, the debugger will show the value as something like "1,2,3,55,99".

Comment: this answer is pretty good don't think you will get a better one

Comment: You never know when Jon Skeet will strike.

Comment: @Neil: nice of you to say so, but the SO idea is that there is always room for improvement. I think sebastian shows that.

Answer (score 1):

I do not like overriding ToString() method in this case. It would be more readable for the developer to define a property which returns a string representation of your desired object.

With `DebuggerDisplay` it would look like this:

```
  [DebuggerDisplay("Values = {DisplayValue}")]
  public struct CommonRow {
    public object[] Values;
    public string DisplayValue
    {
      get
      {
          return Values.Join(",");
      }
    }
  }
```

You can shorten the property with C# 6 (Thanks to @jeppe-stig-nielsen):

```
public string DisplayValue => Values.Join(",");
```

Given your extension class:

```
  public static class UtilExtensions 
  {
    // string join that works on any enumerable
    public static string Join<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, string delim) 
    {
      return String.Join(delim, values.Select(v => v == null ? "null" : v.ToString()));
    }
  {
```

The extension method is obsolete if you use it just one time. You can also write:

```
public string DisplayValue => String.Join(delim, Values.Select(v => v == null ? "null" : v.ToString()));
```

You can find documentation of `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` : msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx or msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Good one. But it would be helpful if you wrote more clearly that this answer refers to the answer by david.pfx himself; otherwise, for example, it is not clear how `.Join(",")` works. _Edit:_ It would also improve the answer if you repeated your web link to the `[DebuggerDisplay]` documentation from your comment above.

Comment: With C# 6.0, one can also write `public string DisplayValue => Values.Join(",");` if one prefers that syntax. The result is exactly the same.

Comment: @sebastian: +1 for the idea of sometimes making it debugger-only. But there is no chance it will be used just one time.